# Don't allow user to enter HTML tags in input

Tags: php, html

I have an input which allows users to enter text, which is then sent using PHP to another page, where it is stored in a database. I have done some simple validation ( checking if the input wasn't empty), and that works pretty well. However, I found out that I can type in HTML tags, such as

```
<p>
```

and it bypasses that validation and also messes up the input.

How can I check if the input contained HTML tags, and if so, return an error?

Comment: what about strip_tags ?

Comment: use strip_tags http://www.php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check try this:

```
if( preg_match('#^<.>.+</.>$#', $your_value) ){
    echo "NOT GOOD";  // and some error too
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), or [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) before inserting into database.

You can also use [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO::quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) to secure strings

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
<input type='text' pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+'>
```

That ensures only letters and numbers can go in and wont submit if anything else is inside the input.

However, this is only good client side and will only work for IE9+

This is also not the best method for validation if someone knows what they're doing.  All they have to do is go into the source code to take out the `pattern` attribute, but for those who don't know, it will be fine.

For the PHP, you can use `strip_tags()`. [Found here](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: Note this is relatively new functionality, and not supported in IE9. Also, no need to use self-closing syntax (/>)

Comment: I added a php bit too @unknown and I will add in the warnings now